# Response Redirect not working after login

Tags: asp.net

I have write a below code in ASP.net to redirect Default page after login successful,but **response.write** function is not working.Please check below code and advise how to do this...

```
 protected void LogIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Login = new DataTable();

        string username = Request.Form["username"];
        string password = Request.Form["password"];
        bool remember = RememberMe.Checked;

        Login = Db.SetCommand("Select * from KhArind.Dbo.UserMaster Where UserName = '" + username + "' And Password = '" + password + "' ").ExecuteDataTable();

        if (Login.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = Login.Rows[0]["UserName"];
            Session["UserId"] = Login.Rows[0]["UserId"];
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",false);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = "Invalid UserName or Password";
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Please check aspx code in below link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/igjlylzqe8fbcq0/ASPXCode.txt?dl=0

ScreenShot for Browser :-

[image]

Comment: Before redirection be careful to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: No Muzaffer,I have removed login condition and just put "Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",false);" but why still response.redirect not working ?

Comment: Try `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", true);`

Comment: That too I tried,but still not working....

Comment: Is IsPostBack enabled? Can you share your aspx source?

Comment: You should share your full code maybe.

Comment: please check code in above link

Answer (score 0):

Before going to the page transferring methods make sure that you have Ispostback is enabled and in page load following section is there or not

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Now try with redirection method

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", true);
```

Still the Response.redirect is not working.
Then go to design view select the button which you want to set Response.redirect and press **F4** that will open Button Properties then you need to find PostBackUrl option and then locate your URL that you want.

[image: PostackURL]

Then locate the file

[image: Files]

See the correct path of your page and add the same on your redirect method

[image]

Comment: please check attached screenshot for browser

Comment: @KH IT : instead of calling at the end add the response.direct at the top of your code and check whether the navigation is working or not.

Comment: I have recheck again in browser,it shows an 302 status code (response).Please advise how to do this...

Comment: i think the problem is with your aspx file location, can you add the project folder structure in the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);`
2. If at root, use "~/", Use `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);`
3. The Transfer method is typically more efficient because it does not cause a round trip to the client. `Server.Transfer("Default.aspx", True)`

Comment: I have tried all above solution but still I am facing the same issue.Actually I have changed the visual studio and windows version.Is there any issue for upgrading windows and visual studio ???

Comment: no it should not cause any issue, which asp.net version are you using? .net framework 4.0 or 5.2 etc?

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2015, but now I am using Visual Studio 2017 with 4.5.2 framework and windows version is windows 10

Comment: Okay, can you set a breakpoint and check if the execution is going inside `if (Login.Rows.Count > 0)` this if block

Comment: yes its going but the problem is why response.redirect not executing ??

Comment: Okay, so next What's the happening after this `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",false);`? What are you seeing in browser? any exception? Do you have 'Default.aspx' or any spelling error? Can you wrap the line in try catch and check if any exception is being thrown?